# How to update a string with new value in java?

Tags: java

I am new to java and working on file operations. I have this input and modify text files as follows:

**input.txt:** contains id,firstname,lastname

```
1000:Mark,Peters,3.9
```

**modify.txt:** contains id,oldvalue:newvalue

```
1000,Mark:John
```

I am supposed to search the id and make the updations accordingly. So in modify.txt file I have an id and old value which is to be replaced with new value in the input.txt

So after modification, my input.txt line output should be printed as:

```
1000:John,Peters,3.9
```

I have written the following code, but I am not sure how to proceed with updations. However, I have managed to read the files and split it and get the id.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedReader file1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("src/input.txt")));
            BufferedReader file2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("src/modify.txt")));
            String str1 = file1.readLine();
            String input[] = str1.split(":");
            int id1 = Integer.parseInt(input[0]);
            System.out.println(str1);
            System.out.println(id1);
            String str2 = file2.readLine();
            String modify[] = str2.split(",");
            int id2 = Integer.parseInt(modify[0]);
            System.out.println(str2);
            System.out.println(id2);
            file1.close();
            file2.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks. Appreciate your help.

Comment: does the modify.txt always contain id, old name and new name?

Comment: May we assume that the modifications called for in `modify.txt` won't necessarily be so convenient as replacing one string of a given length with another string of the exact same length? In other words, we might have `1000,Mark:John`, but we could also just as easily have `1000,Mark:Constantine` or `1000,Alexandrina:Jo`?

Comment: @deadshot, modify.txt can contain any value for which modification needs to be done. For eg, it can ask to modify last name or gpa also.

Comment: @KevinAnderson, yeah string can be of any length kevin.

Comment: Your current code assumes there's going to be just 1 line in both files. Is that a fair assumption?

Comment: @Nishit, yeah there's only one line.

Comment: Do you need to keep the textual form of the file? Or you can use any type of serialization?

Comment: @OlimpiuPOP, any type of serialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the line in `modify.txt` file and split the line using regex `[,:]`. It will split the line into separate parts like id, firstName and lastName etc.

After read the each line in `input.txt` file and and split the each line using the regex `[,:]`. And compare the first element in the list with element in the list created from `modify.txt` file. if the element is equals replace the line with the new data from list created from `modify.txt` file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        BufferedReader f1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("src/input.txt")));
        BufferedReader f2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("src/modify.txt")));

        String regex = "[,:]";
        StringBuffer inputBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        String[] newLine = f2.readLine().split(regex);

        while ((line = f1.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] data = line.split(regex);
            if (data[0].equals(newLine[0])) {
                line = line.replace(newLine[1], newLine[2]);
            }
            inputBuffer.append(line);
            inputBuffer.append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        f1.close();
        f2.close();
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("src/input.txt");
        fileOut.write(inputBuffer.toString().getBytes());
        fileOut.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do i handle if multiple input and modify lines specified?

Comment: store the input.txt content in a list then loop through each line in modify .txt file